# how to get multiple a tags within multiple divs in Html having same names with help of Html agility pack,

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

```
<div class="itemMenu level1">
    <a class="itemMenuName level1" href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac">
        <span>MacBook</span>    
    </a>
    // here a more divs in this div which are submenu items and this level1 div ends under them
</div>
```

I want to get that href link in a tag within that div,
my code is below

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='megnor-advanced-menu-popup_inner']"))
{  
    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("./a[@class='itemMenuName level1']"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node2.InnerText + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(node2.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
    }
```

I am getting whole block of code with first loop but second loop is giving me the error of `NullReference`

Comment: use two slashes to find deeper that children `.//a[@class='itemMenuName level1']` or `./div[a[@class='itemMenuName level1']]/a`

Comment: You code fragment does not match the html fragment.  There is no class `megnor-advanced-menu-popup_inner` in the html.

Comment: thank u everyone, my problem is solved